# Folder outside of root folder and URL Rewrites

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

is the following scenario possible and how do I archive that in a shared hosting environment?

I have a Wordpress installation which resides in, say,

```
/httpdocs/wordpress
```

My domain points to this folder. So calling

```
http://example.com
```

results in the Wordpress page. Now I want to add a second system. But I don't want to pollute my Wordpress and want to store it outside of this folder. I still want it to be accessible via

```
http://example.com/other-system
```

even though it resides in the filesystem in

```
/httpdocs/other-system
```

and not

```
/httpdocs/wordpress/other-system
```

Is that possible? Am I making any sense? Thanks!

Comment: which web server are you using? Apache? please post your current virtual host configuration of your respective web server for this example

Comment: The problem is, that this is hosted in a shared environment, so I can only work with .htaccess. I cannot change the vhost settings myself. It is Apache, if that is of any help. It's a clients site so I cannot do that much to change the environment...

Comment: Since this is a shared hosting environment, don't you have any control panel interface? Parallels Plesk perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is

```
Alias /other-system /httpdocs/other-system
```

See [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).  In .htaccess, instead you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/other-system/(.*)  /httpdocs/other-system/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Alias wont work in .htaccess

Comment: Alias looks exactly like what I need. Sadly it is a shared hosting environment so I can only work with .htaccess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Added equivalent RewriteRule.

Comment: RewriteRule in .htaccess does not work as in server config. Your rewrite rule will not work: example.com/other-system/ => other-system/ => does not match (Note the abscence of begin "/"). If you remove begin "/", you have a match but example.com/other-system/ => example.com/httpdocs/other-system...

Comment: core:error The given path was above the root path

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot use RewriteRule in .htaccess files to go out of your DocumentRoot, because this DocumentRoot will always be added at the beginning of the rewritten url.

I would advise to put each app in a separate folder under your DocumentRoot. For example, use  DocRoot/wordpress and DocRoot/other.

Now if you want nice urls like

```
www.example.com => wordpress app
```

`www.example.com/other => the other-system app`

and also want that url like `www.example.com/wordpress` are redirected to `www.example.com`, then you could use something like the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=""
RewriteRule .  -  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/other/(.*)?$
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/.*$
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

The second rewrite rule matches the other app, does nothing but sets it as the last rewrite in this pass.

The third rewrite makes a permanent redirect from example.com/wordpress to example.com.

Now the first rule does nothing too but if the redirect is set to something in the pass before, it stops. This avoids an infinite redirect loop.

The last rewrite redirects internally everything to wordpress folder. Url in browser stays without the wordpress folder in it.

I’d be curious to know if it works with your apps... Hope it brings you further.